# Problem with poker package

Tags: packages

I am new to latex and i have the following problem.
When i use the poker package the following error occurs "poker.sty" not found. I'm using miktex and texmakerx. What is wrong ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Since the `poker` package is not on CTAN, you'll need to download and install it yourself. For MikTeX, you may find the directions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) helpful.

Comment: Ty Paul that helped. But know i get a new error.  I have the following:                        \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{poker}
\begin{document}
\begin{cards}
\crdKs 
\end{cards}
\end{document}                                                         and i get this error message Undefined control sequence \crdKs. I have read its because it can not be compiled directly to pdf. And that i have to do like this "LaTeX → DVI → PS → PDF". But how do i compile it that way so it end up in pdf. I cant make it work that way.

Comment: `poker.sty` uses `pst-all` and `pst-blur` packages from `pstricks`, hence the error message concerning \crdKs, if the user tries to compile the document with pdflatex. You have to go the long way round via "latex -> dvipdf".

I am afraid, there is no direct compilation to `pdf`.